# Replacement for cmd.exe displaying Unicode characters

Tags: windows, command-line, python, unicode

I have a problem with display of Unicode characters in Windows console environment (cmd.exe, Python scripts being run in console window, etc.). Namely supplementary characters (those corresponding to codepoints ≥ U+10000) are treated as a pair of two independent characters (surrogate pair codepoints). Also combined characters in NFD are displayed series of individual characters instead of one composed character.

I'm looking for a solution which might be based on some kind of replacement of cmd.exe or Windows console environment with something else. From what I have tried, only ConEmu was capable of right treatment of supplementary characters but not combined characters.

I know that there are many problems with Unicode. These problems have nothing to do with setting a right codepage (like chcp 65001) or using inappropriate font. This seems to be inherent incapability of Windows console environment.

Comment: If you really need a product solution for your problem, check out this [meta question] (http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5372/how-do-i-ask-a-question-that-may-require-recommending-software) and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: @user99572isfine: I have tried to reformulate the question.

Comment: Interesting, what is the source of text output with (codepoints ≥ U+10000)? Examples of your texts? Actually, Windows console is usually limited to wchar_t (<=U+FFFF) with only exclusion of DBCS codepages. ConEmu was designed to display text "cell-by-cell" because of text alignments...

Comment: @Maximus: Yes Windows console is limited to wchar_t which means that if you want to give it supplementary character, you encode it as surrogate pair. (And pasting or using UnicodeInput and probably also keyboard itself (if given layout containing the char) does this.) The problem is that the console doesn't know about surrogate pairs and just display them as two (undisplayable – just two boxes) characters.

Comment: @Maximus: As for ConEmu, when I enter a supplementary charater being present in the font it is displayed, however there is some space before, I need to hit backspace twice to get rid of it, and when I try to copy it, there is only second member of supplementary pair. Also base character + combining character isn't displayed as one character.

Comment: You may create an issue on ConEmu project site, with examples of how you typing characters and font which can display them.

Comment: So, you have not created an issue. Why? The problem is not actual to you?

Comment: @Maximus: Sorry, maybe I just forgot. Also the Unicode problems form a big knot of intertwined bugs, this issue was just one of them. Anyway, I just created as issue: https://code.google.com/p/conemu-maximus5/issues/detail?id=1771 .